# Dynamically allocate memory to a char-pointer

Tags: c++, string, char, dynamic-allocation

Is this correct code or should I dynamically allocate memory to the member-variable of the String-class that receives the char-pointer?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class String {
    char *string;
public:
    String(char *ch) {
    string = ch;
}

void print() {
    cout << string;
}

};

int main() {

   String string("hello");
   string.print();

return 0;
```

}

Comment: This depends on your use case. The **correct** way to handle strings in c++ is to use `std::string`

Comment: you should assert that ch points to a char vector and not to NULL. Also, as @πάνταῥεῖ said, you should use std::string

Answer (score 2):

Let start from statement

```
String string("hello");
```

Here "hello" is a string literal. Used as an argument it is implicitly converted to an object of type

```
const char *
```

So the corresponding data member of the class should be defined as

```
const char *string;
```

And as the result the class should be defined as

```
class String 
{
private:
    const char *string;
public:
    String( const char *ch ) : string( ch )
    {
    }

    void print() const 
    {
        cout << string;
    }
};
```

As string literals have static storage duration then your code is valid. Take into account that the class does not possess the pointer.

On the other hand if you want that the class indeed possesses the pointer then you need dynamically allocate a copy of the data pointed to by the constructor argument. In this case you need also explicitly define at least the copy constructor, copy assignment operator, and destructor.