# Operator overloading for Strings

Tags: c++, string, operator-overloading

I cannot see whats wrong with the codesnippet below where I try to overload the operator "=".
I can build it but not run it (it crashes). Its due to the following syntax in the main method:

```
string2 = "my world!";
```

As far as I know - on the left handside of the operator is the object that holds the operator overloaded function and recevies the string-literal (that is passed to the function as an argument) on the right side of the operator.

below is the full code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class String {

public:
char *string;
String(char *ch) {
    string = ch;
}
String (String &string_obj) {
    string = string_obj.string;
}
String operator=(char *ch) {

    strcpy(string, ch);

    return *this;
}

};

ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream, String obj) {

    stream << obj.string;

    return stream;
}



int main() {

   String string("hello ");
   String string2(string);
   cout << string << string2;

   string2 = "my world!";
   cout << string2;



return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code is broken in several aspects. It is not exception-safe, leaks memory and produces redundant copies (at least pre-C++11). I hope this is just for learning, not anything used in real code. And I hope you are aware of `std::string`...

Comment: The point is: I guess you should get these basic things right before tackling operator overloading. Read about the "Rule of Three".

Comment: Please, reread my answer on your previous [post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23441919/dynamically-allocate-memory-to-a-char-pointer/23442021#23442021

Comment: Before using any pointer, you must make it point to some valid memory (by new or initializing with some exiting object) to ensure a defined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

you are passing a constant literal in function in this line `String string("hello ");`
and when you are doing `strcpy` inside `String operator=(char *ch)` it is trying to modify the content of a constant memory location leading the problem to crash.

you can try by doing this

```
int main() {
   char str[]="hello";    
   String string(str);
   String string2(string);
   cout << string << string2;

   string2 = "my world!";
   cout << string2;



return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `operator=` you are trying to copy the contents of `char*` to member variable `string`, but it can be `NULL`, it may not have enough memory to hold copied string. There are also other problem in you code like not passing `const` reference to copy constructor etc. I think you should first learn the basics before trying to overload operators.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is broken in many ways. If this is for learning purposes, you should take a look [at existing implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466073/how-is-stdstring-implemented) of `std::string`. If you are planning on using that class in production code: **don't**, and just use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your String class should have value semantic, and it doesn't. Secondly, you are not allocating any memory for your String.